# Hadoop: Map Reduce: read from HBase, but filter rows by content of one column

Tags: hadoop, filter, mapreduce, hbase, database-scan

I am really new to Hadoop and I am not able to find an answer to my question. I want to write a map reduce job, where I read from HBase and write then in a simple text file.

In HBase, Ive got a column representing an id. Now I dont want to work on *all* containing rows in my HBase Table, but only on those between a maxId and a minId.

I found out that I could possibly user filters `(scan.setFilter)`, so that I can filter rows which dont match my request.

This is my first Map Reduce Job, so please be patient :-)

Ive got a Starter Class, where I configure the job and the Scan Object and then start the job.

Now, my first try looks like this:

```
private Scan getScan()
{
    final Scan scan = new Scan();

    // ** FILTER **
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    Filter filter1 = new ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(minId))));
    filters.add(filter1);

    Filter filter2 = new ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(maxId))));
    filters.add(filter2);

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(filters);

    scan.setFilter(filterList); 

    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
    // id
    scan.addColumn("columnfamily".getBytes(), "id".getBytes());
    return scan;
}
```

Well, Im not sure if this is the right way to do it. I also read that I could pass my minId and maxId maybe with the Configuration Object to the Map Job, but Im not sure how.

Besides, what have I to do afterwards? I would normally just initiate the job with `initTableMapperJob` and pass the Scan Object to it. Ive read something of ResultScanner and so, do I need them? I thought the MapReduce Framework would now automatically pass the correct rows to my map job, is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like a right way.  What version of HBase are you using?